# Spring Data JPA Hibernate fetching @OneToOne returns infinite loop of bidirectional entities

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working on saving an `Employee` record with its `EmployeeIdCard` **bidirectional** with `@OneToOne` and `fetch = Lazy`. While debugging my `EmployeeRepository.findById()` test case, I found this looping `EmployeeIdCard.employee`.
[image]

Although this is not the case when it is returned into the `EmployeeService` but I want to understand what exactly is happening here. If I understand it correctly, this will loop infinitely. Is this normal? What could be causing this to happen and how to fix this? Below are the entities (removed other fields for simplicity).

```java
// Employee.java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Employee")
@Table(
  name = "employee",
  uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(name = "employee_email_unique", columnNames = "email")
  }
)
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
  private String firstName;

  @OneToOne(
    mappedBy = "employee",
    orphanRemoval = true,
    cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE},
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY
  )
  @ToString.Exclude
  @LazyToOne(NO_PROXY)
  private EmployeeIdCard employeeIdCard;

}
```

```java
// EmployeeIdCard.java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "EmployeeIdCard")
@Table(
  name = "employee_id_card",
  uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(name = "employee_id_card_number_unique", columnNames = "card_number")
  }
)
public class EmployeeIdCard {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(
    name = "idcard_sequence",
    sequenceName = "idcard_sequence",
    allocationSize = 1
  )
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "idcard_sequence")
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "card_number", nullable = false, length = 8)
  private String cardNumber;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(
    name = "employee_id",
    referencedColumnName = "id",
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "employee_id_card_employee_id_fk")
  )
  @ToString.Exclude
  @LazyToOne(NO_PROXY)
  private Employee employee;

}
```

**EDIT 1:** when fetching the parent entity (id), not saving

**EDIT 2:**
The same behavior when setting up the parent-child before the save/fetch call.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add this  **@JsonIgnore** annotation  on **EmployeeIdCard** Entity with Employee properties (Keep other annotation as like as before)

As:

```
class EmployeeIdCard {
  .
  .

@JsonIgnore
private Employee employee;

}
```

Comment: I added this. Removed `@ToString` on both entities and still got the same. Tried rebuilding also